# The annotation @DisplayName of JUnit Jupiter is not recognized by Intellij Idea Community

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, junit, junit5

I have written some unit test using JUnit 5.4, Java 8, Gradle 6.3 and Intellij Idea Community 2020.1.

I tried to use the @DisplayName annotation and when I run the test in Intellij the annotation value is not display in the run test results but when I run the test using Gradle, the annotation works perfectly.

This is my code:

```java
@DisplayName("A bookshelf")
class BookShelfTests {

    private BookShelf shelf;

    @BeforeEach
    void init() throws Exception {
        shelf = new BookShelf();
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("is empty when no book is added to it")
    void shelfEmptyWhenNoBookAdded() throws Exception {
        List<Book> books = shelf.books();
        assertTrue(books.isEmpty(), "BookShel should be empty");
    }
}
```

And this is the result when I run the test with Intellij:
[image: Intellij run test result]

And this is the result when I run the test with Gradle:
[image]

Please, could some help me to understand what I need to do to configure Intellij to show up the JUnit @Display value?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

It’s not an IntelliJ problem but a Gradle problem. Gradle does not fully support display names. The fix, however, is easy: Go to Gradle Preferences and set „Run tests using: IntelliJ IDEA“.

Comment: It woks. Thank you!! But I think that is an issue with the Gladle integration into Intellij because if I run `gradle test` works perfectly.